# How to get value from nsmallest instead of .core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas

Pretty new to python so any advice is always welcome.

I am trying to map data from multiple sets of coordinates to one set and am trying to use Bilinear interpolation to do it.

I have a set of DataFrames I iterate over and am trying to find the nearest neighbors for my interpolation.

Since my grids may not be uniform in spacing I am sorting by Y position first:

```
for i in range(0, len(df_x['X'])):
    x_pos = df_x._get_value(i, 'X')#pull x coord y coord
    y_pos = df_y._get_value(i, 'Y')
    for n in data_list:
        df = data_list[n] #
        d_y = abs(df['Y'] - y_pos) #array of distance from Y pos
        d_y.drop_duplicates() # remove duplicates
        
        nn_y1 = d_y.nsmallest(1) # finds closest row
        nn_y2 = d_y.nsmallest(2).iloc[-1] # finds next closest row
        
        print(type(nn_y1))

        d_x_y1 = df[df['DesignY'] == nn_y1] # creates list of X at closest row
```

I think this should provide me with my upper and lower bounds nearest my points.

however when then sorting for X position I get an error

`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

I think this is due to the fact that the type for `nn_y1` kicks out `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

any advice for how to get the value instead of the series? I could create a dataframe with one element but that seems hacky? I tried some combinations of `_get_value()` but to no avail.

Comment: This solved it! Any idea why that worked but ```nn_y1 = d_y.nsmallest(1)``` didnt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`nsmallest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html#pandas-series-nsmallest) returns:

> "The n smallest values in the Series, sorted in increasing order." (Type [**Series**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas-series))

In this case the simple way is to unpack from `nsmallest(2)` since both values are needed:

```
nn_y1, nn_y2 = d_y.nsmallest(2)
```

---

To modify the code directly [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html#pandas-series-iloc) is needed to get the first value from the Series:

```
nn_y1 = d_y.nsmallest(1).iloc[0]
```

---

Alternatively `d_y.nsmallest(2)` could've been used twice with `iloc` to get both values:

```
smallest = d_y.nsmallest(2)
nn_y1 = smallest.iloc[0]
nn_y2 = smallest.iloc[1]
```